# How to prevent Slick plugin from removing event listeners

Tags: slick.js

This is my actual slick gallery, I added an 'click' event listener on the "?" button... but when the gallery hits the breakpoint, slick will remove all the event listeners... how can i prevent that?

```
$('.qmark-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // var img = $(this);
        alert('test');
});
$('.img-gallery').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        arrows: false,
        rows: 3,
        infinite: false,

        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1200,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 5,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 992,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                }
            }

        ]
    });
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's the slick plugin who is removing your `click`event listener. Is your "?" button generated at load, or is it dynamically added on hover or something?

Comment: they're static buttons.

Comment: Weirdly, I was able to reproduce the issue. You should try to attach the event as if the button was dynamically added. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/89s5gf81/2/)

Comment: i've already tried that one.. still not working.

Comment: If you created a fiddle corresponding to what you have, it'd be easier for me to help

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same problem and fixed it with a small tweak to the cleanUpRows function within slick.js.

```
Slick.prototype.cleanUpRows = function() {
    var _ = this, originalSlides;

    if(_.options.rows > 1) {
        originalSlides = _.$slides.children().children().clone(true);
        originalSlides.removeAttr('style');
        _.$slider.empty().append(originalSlides);
    }

};
```

Simply add  ".clone(true)".
This copies eventlisteners to originalSlides.

This fixed my issues with Slick when a responsive break was hit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with cloning is that it only keeps jquery related handlers and will not preserve things like vanilla js events and references to the old node that may exist in your code. To keep all of this, we want to avoid cloning the elements AND avoid using the `empty()` jquery function which removes all jquery handler, so one solution would be to replace this function by emptying the content with a simple use of innerHTML:

```
Slick.prototype.cleanUpRows = function() {
    var _ = this, originalSlides;

    if(_.options.rows > 1) {
        originalSlides = _.$slides.children().children().clone(true);
        originalSlides.removeAttr('style');
        _.$slider.get(0).innerHTML = '';
        _.$slider.append(originalSlides);
    }

};
```

or use a documentFragment:

```
Slick.prototype.cleanUpRows = function() {

    var _ = this, originalSlides;

    if(_.options.rows > 0) {
        originalSlides = _.$slides.children().children()
        originalSlides.removeAttr('style');

        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        _.$slides.children().each(function(i, element) {
            while(element.firstChild) {
                fragment.appendChild(element.firstChild);
            }
            element.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, element);
        })
    }

};
```